# Why is min() giving bizarre results?

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic

While debugging a program in Visual Studio 2013, I found something strange. In one expression where I use min(), strange values appear.  In the Immediate Window in VS, I try this:

```
min(W, H)
35 '#'
W
291
H
682
```

Duh-what??   What is the explanation of this?

Comment: Looks like some conversion to an 8-bit type is performed: 35 dec == 23 hex, and 291 dec == 123 hex, 682 dec == 2AA hex. When truncating at 8 bit, we get `min(0x23, 0xAA) == 0x23`.

Comment: What code produced that output?

Comment: ... and the definition of `min()` is?

Comment: The fact that the `35` is followed by `'#'` is also an indication, in addition to what @dyp commented, that the debugger sees something involving `char` (or maybe `unsigned char`) types.

Comment: As far as I know, the VS debugger's Immediate window doesn't evaluate macros, so you must have a function implementation of `min()` that's being used. The SDK's implementation of `min()` is a macro, and `std::min()` is a template that I also believe would be unavailable to the Immediate window evaluation (at least it's not obvious to me how to get the Immediate window to evaluate something with `std::min()`).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I wonder if `using namespace std;` is involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` is treating its inputs as `char`s. That's why it shows the character `'#'` next to `35`, because the ascii value of 35 is #. The numbers you are giving are out of the range of a `char`, so they are wrapping. You're really doing `min(291%256, 682%256)` which is `min(35, 170)` which is obviously `35`.

Comment: I found out today that I wasn't including header for min(), max().  I did have a special definition for my own byte type.  Why it was used when given ints (32-bit) w/o any warnings, I dunno.    But now I have math.h and other headers, so problem solved.